# counter value not display properly in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

ia am new to angular... i try to increase and decrease product quantity in  cart page ... in my first index it works fine... in second index value start with first index value when increment counter

my html page

```
<mat-card class="example-card"  *ngFor="let searched of searchedDataResult;let indexOfelement=index;">
         
            <div class="col-2 ">
               
                <mat-form-field >
                    <button
                      mat-button
                      mat-icon-button
                      matPrefix
                      aria-label="Remove"
                      [color]="getColor()"
                      (click)="incrementValue(-1,indexOfelement)"
                      [disabled]="shouldDisableDecrement(searched._value)"
                    >
                      <mat-icon>remove</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                    <input 
                      matInput 
                      type="number"  id="getval_{{indexOfelement}}"
                    value="{{searched._value}}" 
                       
                      (focus)="setColor('primary')"
                      (blur)="setColor('default')"
                    />
                   
                    <button
                      mat-button
                      mat-icon-button
                      matSuffix
                      aria-label="Add"
                      [color]="getColor()"
                      (click)="incrementValue(1,indexOfelement)"
                      [disabled]="shouldDisableIncrement(searched._value)"
                    >
                      <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                  </mat-form-field>
                <button mat-flat-button style="background-color: #1d857b;color:white"  (click)="getaddedmedcine(searched.id,indexOfelement,searched.amount)" >  Add To Cart</button>
           
    </mat-card>
```

this is my ts file

```
incrementValue(step: number = 1,index:number): void {
  
  this._value += step;
  this.searchedDataResult[index]._value=this._value;
  
 }
```

how to reset initial value start with 1 for every index for increment decrement counter...please help me

Answer (score 0):

you should have an array also to count number of each product. You should have something like that :

```
incrementValue(step: number = 1,index:number): void {
    this._value[index] += step;
    this.searchedDataResult[index]._value=this._value[index];
}
```

Comment: i tried this code but it shows `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0').... i declare this variable  _value: any; ...

Comment: errazki.sibawaih( if i add this means increment does not work it shows 0 only)